# Different AUC result from tf.py_func and sklearn during training in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to calculate the AUC of validation set(x_val,y_val) each epoch when I train my model by roc_auc_curve in sklearn.metrics.

After I stack my neural network model:

```
model=Sequential()
      .
      .
      .
model.add(Dense(...))
```

I have two different method to calculate AUC.
The first one is by tf.py_func:

```
def auc(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.py_func(roc_auc_score, (y_true, y_pred), tf.double)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy',auc])
model.fit(...,validation_data=(x_val,y_val),...)
```

And the second is by keras.callbacks:

```
class train_history(Callback):
    def __init__(self,validation_data):
        self.x_val = validation_data[0]
        self.y_val = validation_data[1]
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.val_auc= []
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        y_pred_val = self.model.predict(self.x_val)
        val_rocauc = roc_auc_score(self.y_val, y_pred_val)
        self.val_auc.append(logs['val_rocauc'])
his=train_history(validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
checkpoint=[his]
model.fit(...,validation_data=(x_val,y_val),callbacks=checkpoint,...)
```

But the result from these two methods are different. And the second one seems correctly after I check these two methods.

Is there any one know why? Thanks a lot.